# Question about lemma involving discriminant of field extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to understand a proof given in Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory of the following lemma: Let $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ be a basis of $L/K$ which is contained in $B$, the algebraic closure of $A$ in $L$, of discriminant $d=d(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$. Then one has $dB\subseteq A\alpha_1+\cdots A\alpha_n$. The proof goes as follows: If $\alpha=a_1\alpha_1+\cdots a_n\alpha_n\in B$, $a_j\in K$, then the $a_j$ are a solutions of the system of linear equations $\operatorname{Tr}_{L/K}(\alpha_i\alpha)=\sum_j\operatorname{Tr}_{L/K}(\alpha_i\alpha_j)a_j$, and as $\operatorname{Tr}_{L/K}(\alpha_i\alpha)\in A$, they are given as the quotient of an element of $A$ by the determinant $\det(\operatorname{Tr}_{L/K}(\alpha_i\alpha))=d$.

My question is, why can the $a_j$ be expressed as such a quotient? I don't see how the matrix equation coming from the system of linear equations above implies this.

Is it because we can scale out a $d$ from a row different from $j$ and divide through by $d$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_rule); an expression for the solution of a linear system, with the determinant in the denominator.